# How do you do web animation of objects to come in,where their place becomes visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, css-animations

I need to make "entrance" animation to a lot of objects. They should fly from sides of pages to places they are meant to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery **[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate)** .